# Changing AngularJS number input range

Tags: angularjs, ionic-v1

I have a very simple question for you. I am currently trying to change the allowed input in my label depending on which ID of the tab I am currently at.

It is a hotel booking app using ionic 1 and angular. 
Say I am at the hotelroom with an ID of '1', then I want to set the maximum input to 2. But if Im at hotelroom with an ID of '2' I want to set the maximum to 5. 
Can it be done solely within the label tags?

```
<label class="item item-input">
  <input type="number" name="adults" required 
placeholder="Antal vuxna" ng-model="data.people">
</label>
```

Answers shown as examples are highly appreciated :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are two options I can think of.  Option A, use `ng-if` based on the hotelroom ID and change the max value attribute on the inputs.  Option B, use `ng-change` and validate the value when the user changes it.

Answer (score 3):

Use either, the `max` attribute with [interpolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation):

```
<input type="number" name="adults" max="{{maxPeople}}" required 
       placeholder="Antal vuxna" ng-model="data.people" />
```

OR the `ng-max` attribute with an [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression):

```
<input type="number" name="adults" ng-max="maxPeople" required 
       placeholder="Antal vuxna" ng-model="data.people" />
```

JS

```
$scope.maxPeople = 2;
if ( hotelroom.ID == 2 ) {
    $scope.maxPeople = 5;
};
```

For more information, see [AngularJS `<input type=number` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D),